# Why does my PHP file have a period underscore at the start of the file?

Tags: php

I'm taking over a project from a developer that is no longer here. I opened an older project and noticed something odd:

[image]

There are files with a `._` at the start of the file. Inside the file it shows:

[image]

I've never seen this before. I figured it was perhaps a compiled version of the file, but I don't think so. The site was originally written in PHP 5.6, and later converted to PHP 7.0.

Any thoughts on what these files are for? I'm quite new to PHP, so I really have no clue.

I found this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them) but this is for OSX, which got me to thinking that this might be a linux thing. The site was originally developed on linux. So maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: I suppose the previous dev worked on a Mac? I seem to remember they are Mac OS artifacts holding some kind of metadata about the file. Nothing specific to PHP anyway.

Comment: He did not. But he did work on Linux. I have updated my question to include a link to the OSX information, so might be related.

Comment: Mac OS has hidden files like that for rollback

Comment: ._ files store information about the actual file on MAC OS. detailed information can be found here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them

Comment: Would they also do this for an older version of Linux?

Comment: They're Mac files. Someone, at some point used a Mac to edit locally and decided to upload the entire folder.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus really odd, because we've never had a Mac here. I'm assuming they are safe to delete

Comment: Nobody ever worked from home; on their personal Mac? Do interns bring their personal computers? Is that code base available as a shared drive on the network or on some kind of cloud storage such as Dropbox? If a Mac connects to such storage then it creates those files.

Comment: I'm wondering if someone had dropbox then and synced to a home computer. If these are 100% mac only then that would be the only case that I can think of. Not once ever has IT developed on a Mac.

Comment: Cool, feel free to ignore those files or delete them. They have nothing to do with standard PHP nor Linux.